# Give an example of a non constant uniformly differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Give an example of a non constant uniformly differentiable function with domain $[0,1]$ identify it's derivative and justify your assertions. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I know that the definition of a uniformly differentiable function is the following

A differentiable function $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ is said to be uniformly differentiable on $[a,b]$ if $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0:\forall x,y\in[a,b]$ we have $$0<|x-y|<\delta\implies |\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-f'(y)|<\epsilon$$

i don't know where to go from here, i was thinking the function $f(x)=x$  is this correct? it's continuous on $[0,1]$

Comment: You meant find $f $ uniformly differentiable and supported on $[0,1]$ ? Then look at $(1-\cos(x)) 1_{x \in [0,2\pi]}$

Comment: your example is correct.

Comment: my example? @james.nixon

Comment: Your example works. If $f$ is a linear function then $(f(x)-f(y))/(x-y)-f'(x)=0$ whenever $x\ne y.$